# Multiple approaches to one conditional problem

Tags: probability

Here's the question:
Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed on the diamond $|x| + |y|<1$ Find $P(Y>1/4 | X=1/2)$.

My approach:
1) Draw the diamond.
2) Fix the line $x=1/2$
3) Draw the line $y=1/4$
4) Use double integral over the little triangle: $\int_{1/2}^{3/4}dx\int_{1/4}^{1-x} \frac{1}{2}dx$, where $\frac1{2}$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$, found by $\frac{1}{diamond \_ \ area}$ since we have a uniform distribution.

I just don't know why my approach gives me a wrong answer. It makes perfect sense to me. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: If $X=1/2$ then $(X,Y)$ lies on the line, not in the triangle. The probability will be the ratio of lengths of segments.

Comment: @NCh ah it makes sense now. So my approach would be correct if the problem were, $P(Y>1/4 | X>1/2)$? Please help me verify this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you correct properly integration variables (now they both are $x$).

Comment: @NCh But since this is a joint uniform distribution, I can do it by comparing the area of my little triangle with the area of the region corresponding to $P(X>1/2)$. Hmmm, I understand this kind of problem much better now. Thank you so much!

Comment: And also note that this integral equals not to conditional probability, but to the probability of intersection (jointly $Y>1/4, X>1/2$). For conditional probability you should to divide it to the probability of the condition (1/8).